# React Flux Loading Initial Data via API Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have been stuck on this issue for hours now. I want to implement the Flux architecture. I am trying to create a ToDo list. However, I want to load some initial data before hand. For example in my todoStore.js:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

class ToDoStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.bucket_list = [{
            id: 123,
            name: "Hi",
            isCompleted: false
        }]

    }

    getAll(){
        return this.bucket_list;
    }
}
```

I have some initial data here which is used by my `todo.js`:

```
import toDoStore from './stores/todoStore'

class BucketApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bucket_list: toDoStore.getAll()
        };
    }
```

And this works fine and dandy. I have a store which is basically a `collection` that my `component` receives data from. However, now I want to initialize the data from a database. So I have updated my `todoStore.js`:

```
class BucketlistStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(){
        super();
        fetch(url)
            .then(d => d.json())
            .then(d => {
                this.bucket_list = d;
            });
    }

    getAll(){
        return this.bucket_list;
    }
}
```

However, the getAll() returns `undefined`. Why is this the case? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `undefined` because fetching data is async and during initialization `this.bucket_list` is undefined. Try this:

```
class BucketlistStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.bucket_list_promise = fetch(url)
            .then(d => d.json());
    }

    getAll(){
        return this.bucket_list_promise;
    }
}
```

then

```
import toDoStore from './stores/todoStore'

class BucketApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loadingData: true,
            bucket_list: null
        };
    }

    componentWillMount(){
       toDoStore.getAll().then(result => {
          this.setState({ bucket_list: result, loadingData: false }) 
       })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `fetch` is async operation, maybe you call `getAll()` too early? It's not a solution, but you may check the assumption:

```
class BucketlistStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.loading = true;
        fetch(url)
            .then(d => d.json())
            .then(d => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.bucket_list = d;
            });
    }

    getAll(){
        console.log(this.loading);
        return this.bucket_list;
    }
}
```

If it's true, I would suggest just not to render `BucketApp` while `loading` is `true`. Put the flag to store and use it in `BucketApp` to prevent render (show loader instead).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it happens because you component renders itself before ending async fetching. In other words, you get undefined, and when you get result after finishing `fetch`(when your store is updated) you component is not updated. You can apply the techniques described above, OR you can use Redux. In Redux, if store is updated, it cause updates of all components which somehow are connected with Redux store.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I load the initial data on my component state and listen to emit on componentDidMount to update state when promise is resolved. Below an example with your code.

//Store

```
import EventEmitter from "events";
let initState = {
  id: 123,
  name: "Hi",
  isCompleted: false,
  loadingData: true
};

class BucketlistStore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    fetch(url)
      .then(d => d.json())
      .then(d => {
        const { id, name, isCompleted } = d;
        initState = { id, name, isCompleted, loadingData: false };
        this.emit("updated");
      });
  }

  getAll() {
    return initState;
  }
}

export default new BucketlistStore();
```

//Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import toDoStore from "./stores/todoStore";

class BucketApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = toDoStore.getAll();
  }

  updateState = () => {
    const { id, name, isCompleted, loadingData } = toDoStore.getAll();
    this.setState({ id, name, isCompleted, loadingData });
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    toDoStore.on("updated", this.updateState);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    toDoStore.off("updated", this.updateState);
  }

  render() {
    const { id, name, isCompleted, loadingData } = this.state;

    if (loadingData) return <p>Loading...</p>;

    return null; //your code
  }
}
```